Delete duplicate with column is blank
I have a table
emp     checking    saving   cd     contact    type
tom     100.00      100.00  100.00  no          x         
tom     100.00      100.00  100.00  yes         NULL
bob     200.00      200.00  200.00  no          z         
bob     200.00      200.00  200.00  yes         NULL
mike    250.00      100.00  50.00   yes         NULL
alice   500.00      210.00  10.00   yes         NULL

Expect result
emp    checking   saving    cd  contact type
tom    100.00   100.00  100.00  no      x         
bob    200.00   200.00  200.00  no      z         
mike   250.00   100.00  50.00   yes     NULL
alice  500.00   210.00  10.00   yes     NULL

My query
select x.*
from (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by  emp order by type ) as seqnum
      from table1
     ) x
where seqnum = 1

My goal is to remove duplicate records. If ONLY 2 records with identical and need to remove when contact is 'yes'. The query remove all 'No' and does not look correct. Not sure what do I miss here?
Thank for your help.

What constitutes the duplicate?  What fields need to match?  Why do you order by type? Why there is no contact in your logic?

For example look at 2 Tom records, all have same values, except contact, I need when contact  = yes then remove. If single record  I need to keep even contact  = yes

No, type is different as well.
